# Which Stack Exchange site to ask for a method for calculating a salary to ask for based on my hourly rate?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I used to think that the Programmers stack would be the place to do so, but now the Software Engineering closed some questions like it, so is there a place to ask this?

What I want to know is how to calculate a fixed salary based on my hourly rate.
(because I regularly work on a hourly rate, but I might consider full-time positions)

Edit: I'm a PHP developer mostly, I live in Argentina but work for companies abroad, usually American, so both freelance rates and fixed salaries are just what I'm paid, no benefits like health insurance, although I do get paid holidays on full-time jobs.

Also, I'm not looking for someone to tell me what figure to ask for, just a ballpark relation to my hourly rate. For example: *Ask for 80 times your hourly rate as a monthly salary, which would be equal to a 4 hour day freelance work.*

Answer (score 10):

A question about assessing compensation when moving between full-time and contract work would be on topic on [The Workplace](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/), with some caveats:

- We do not cover specific job functions.  If you being a programmer or a plumber or a schoolteacher is key to the computation, we can't help you.  ("How much should programmers make?" is off-topic.  Also primarily opinion-based.)
- Some things can vary by location; for example, if you have nationalized health care already then you don't need to factor health-insurance benefits, but if you don't, you do.  So tell us where in the world you are.
- Every job is different; we, like every other SE site, deal in questions that are more broadly useful, not ones that are only useful to one person.  Try to ask your question with that in mind.
- We can provide guidance, but we can't tell you a number.

Comment: Thanks, I added info on your suggestion.

Comment: Oh sorry; I meant that when you ask your question on The Workplace you should include that information.  Meta.SE isn't the place to get answers about salary.