# Proper SE-site to ask about veterinarian immigrant years income in Canada

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I like to ask this question, but don't know which SE site to ask on. I want know what is the average veterinarian migrant annual income in Canada?

I have seen this [post](https://www.thebalancecareers.com/salary-how-much-do-vets-make-125652) about average incomes of veterinarians in Canada like this:

> The Bureau of Labor Statistics (BLS) reports that veterinarians earn a
>   median salary of $88,770. The best-paid veterinarians earn $161,070,
>   while the lowest-paid earned $52,470. Vets in their first year of
>   practice can expect to earn a salary of approximately $60,000.

So based on [this post](https://neuvoo.ca/salary/?job=indian), the average incomes of migrants in Canada is:

> The average Indian salary in Canada is $34,125 per year or $17.50 per
>   hour. Entry level positions start at $25,350 per year while most
>   experienced workers make up to $49,725 per year.

But my cousin is a veterinarian and says this income is not for migrants veterinarian in Canada. There is a ceiling income for them of $18000 one year before becoming a citizen (maybe after a 5 year period of waiting to become a citizen, even passing the veterans exams).

So where would I ask here to know what is the reality?

Comment: I eddited the title and don't know what is yours mean about proper-site?

Comment: Also depends heavily on which province & city (Although you may also want to consider cost of living).

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/322018/which-stack-exchange-site-to-ask-for-a-method-for-calculating-a-salary-to-ask-fo

Comment: Expatriates might be ok for things like "I am a vet in India, what do I need to do to work as a vet in Canada". To my knowledge, Canada doesn't limit anyone's salary, nor insist that immigrants earn less than citizens. You could ask in Expatriates if that is true. It may be that certain benefits are only paid to those earning less than $18k.

Answer (score 0):

> So where would I ask here to know what is the reality?

As always, you should first conduct your own research. For me, that would start with questioning said cousin. The claims sound stupid, so where did they get them from? Don't let them off the hook. You cannot ask a question or do internet research every time somebody says something stupid. that would take several lifetimes and you only have one. Just confront them and ask for clarification and sources. Maybe they have some. Great. Maybe not. Great also, because that probably means it was animal manure from the start.

The problem is that it is *really hard* to disprove something. If I claimed in Germany Immigrants can only have up to 3 kids and only if at least one of them was born on a Tuesday, good luck finding something on any of that. You will not find *anything* online stating how many children immigrants can have, because there is no rule or law on it. Everybody can have as many as they can possibly make and that's not written down anywhere.

So first, question whoever said something. Ask for clarification. Do an internet search. Then maybe post on [Expatriates](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) since your question is about immigration and living/working in a foreign country.

But be prepared that you get a straight "uh, what? NO!" as an answer, without any sources at all, because there are no sources to cite for what is *allowed*.

And on a personal note: why would Canada prevent you from earning income? Have you *ever* seen a tax authority going "I'm sorry Sir, you are paying too much to the state authorities, please earn less so you pay less, otherwise we will punish you, we cannot have you pay that much money to us". I mean I know it's Canada, but even there tax authorities like getting money. They won't hinder you.

Comment: "And on a personal note: why would Canada prevent you from earning income?" A lot of countries don't allow you to work until you've properly completed the immigration (which can take years). That may be part of the confusion.